# Upload files from EC2 server to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to upload a file from an Amazon Server (EC2) to S3.

First of all, I created a new IAM users named "backup". I attached to this user the managed policy "AmazonS3FullAccess" and this should suffice. Moreover I add the following policy:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I add an access key to the user.

I back to server and I type the ID and Access key by doing `aws configure`.

On S3 bucket configuration user "pinco.pallo" ("backup" is a IAM of "pinco.pallo") has all grantee by default and this should suffice. Moreover, I tried to add the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1425416644138",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1425416630319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:user/backup"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1425416630319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:user/backup"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

By the way, when I try 
`aws s3 cp --sse --region eu-west-1 file s3://bucket/`
I get the following error:
`upload failed: ./file to s3://bucket/file A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

Someone has some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course, If I grant all permission to Everyone, I can copy the file, but this setting is not acceptable for me, because bucket should be private.

Comment: your first listed policy does not have a "principal", a grantee.

Comment: second one lists only bucket as resource, you should add bucket/*

Comment: Thank you mojo, but I don't understand your comments:

(1) my first listed policy refers to an IAM, who should be the "principal"?
(2) second one refers to both bucket and bucket/*

Some ideas?

Comment: Nicola, I took your IAM policy, changed the bucket names to my own and was able to successfully `aws s3 ls` and `aws s3 cp file s3://bucket`. The problem is not with your IAM policy. You mention that you "type the ID and Access key" for `aws configure`, but that command takes an Access Key and Secret Key -- is that what you meant?

Comment: Thank you for your reply John.

Yes, I used an Access Key and Secret Key associated to my IAM.

And yes, now it works. I think I will never known the reason why it did not work two days ago...

Comment: @NicolaSturaroSommacal I have the exact same issue. It sometimes works , sometimes doesn't.

Comment: @NicolaSturaroSommacal And as time passes, the failures are becoming more rare. It might be that it takes time for the new policy to propagate to all s3 servers and that it depends on which server you're hitting.

Answer (score 1):

yea -  similar to how @peycho-dimitrov mentioned, if you want cp and sync to work you need to set permissions and resources as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt20000",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListObjects"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybackup",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybackup/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```